# Python3: Requests.get runs out of memory when hitting livestream/webcam

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, out-of-memory

When i run my python code to load a webpage by using requests.get, i sometime have the problem that the process gets killed, because it runs out of memory.

The memory 'leak' (seems to) occurs when the body is loading. This mainly happens when the website has an embedded video stream (like webcam). The requests.get autoloads the whole stream and it keeps loading until the memory is full and the program crashes.

Example:

```
import requests

url = "http://ip-thomasmarina.greatlakescam.com/user/cgi-bin/getstream.cgi?10&&&&0&0&0&0&0"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64'}, timeout=(1.5), verify=False)
from lxml.html import fromstring
tree = fromstring(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
title = tree.findtext('.//title')
```

In the browser, you can also see that the site just keeps loading new content:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea2CO.jpg

Any suggestions for a fix or workaround to stop the constant loading of data or in general not to autoload or autostart the stream? I just need the html code as my goal is to capture the page title.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you are streaming video content directly. Depends on what your goal is. If you want to capture video frame by frame, you may use `stream=True` kwarg in get. If you want to view content or convert, maybe other programs/libraries like `ffmpeg` are better.

Comment: Thanks you. My goal is to just to capture the webpage title, so plain html.

Comment: There is no title or HTML on the page, it is raw video URL.